# jQuery append() vs appendChild()

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, appendchild

Here's some sample code:

```js
function addTextNode(){
    var newtext = document.createTextNode(" Some text added dynamically. ");
    var para = document.getElementById("p1");
    para.appendChild(newtext);
    $("#p1").append("HI");
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red">
    <p id="p1">First line of paragraph.<br /></p>
</div>
```

What is the difference between `append()` and `appendChild()`?
Any real time scenarios?

Comment: see here http://jsperf.com/native-appendchild-vs-jquery-append/4

Comment: One is a jQuery method, the other is a native JS method, they both do pretty much the same thing, but append() accepts multiple elements.

Comment: The bottom is using a library (e.g. the commonly referenced jQuery), the top is using "native" DOM methods to append the element.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The main difference is that `appendChild` is a DOM method and `append` is a jQuery method. The second one uses the first as you can see on jQuery source code

```
append: function() {
    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
            this.appendChild( elem );
        }
    });
},
```

If you're using jQuery library on your project, you'll be safe always using `append` when adding elements to the page.

Comment: Do you know why append is "safe" and appendChild is not? What does domManip do?

Comment: @RobFox: by safe I meant to say that if you're using jquery then you are safe to use always append (there is no situation where DOM appendchild is prefered). In relation to domManip, it seems the main objective is using DOM DocumentFragments. [Here](http://www.blog.highub.com/javascript/decoding-jquery-dommanip-dom-manipulation/) you have a description of the method and [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) you have the official word of John Resig about motivations behind using fragments

Comment: javascript also has a `ParentNode.append()` now. please check @SagarV's answer for more info.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as @JoE. : see [ParentNode.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).

Answer (score 67):

## No longer

now append is a method in JavaScript

[MDN documentation on append method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

Quoting MDN

> The `ParentNode.append` method inserts a set of Node objects or `DOMString` objects after the last child of the `ParentNode`. `DOMString` objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

This is not supported by IE and Edge but supported by Chrome(54+), Firefox(49+) and Opera(39+).

The JavaScript's append is similar to jQuery's append.

You can pass multiple arguments.

```js
var elm = document.getElementById('div1');
elm.append(document.createElement('p'),document.createElement('span'),document.createElement('div'));
console.log(elm.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 23):

`append` is a jQuery method to append some content or HTML to an element.

```
$('#example').append('Some text or HTML');
```

`appendChild` is a pure DOM method for adding a child element.

```
document.getElementById('example').appendChild(newElement);
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old and answered question and I'm not looking for votes I just want to add an extra little thing that I think might help newcomers.

yes `appendChild` is a `DOM` method and `append` is JQuery method but practically the key difference is that `appendChild` takes a node as a parameter by that I mean if you want to add an empty paragraph to the DOM you need to create that `p` element first

`var p = document.createElement('p')`

then you can add it to the DOM whereas JQuery `append` creates that node for you and adds it to the DOM right away whether it's a text element or an html element
or a combination!

`$('p').append('<span> I have been appended </span>');`

Answer (score 7):

`appendChild` is a DOM [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/) function.

`append` is a jQuery function.

They each have their own quirks.

Comment: This answere is outdated! Look at @Sagar V 's answer for an up to date explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The [JavaScript appendchild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) method can be use to append an item to another element. The [jQuery Append](http://www.yogihosting.com/jquery-append/) element does the same work but certainly in less number of lines:

> Let us take an example to Append an item in a list:

a) With JavaScript

```
var n= document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
var tn = document.createTextNode("JavaScript");      // Create a text node
n.appendChild(tn);                                   // Append the text to <li>
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(n);
```

b) With jQuery

```
$("#myList").append("<li>jQuery</li>")
```

Answer (score 0):

`appendChild` is a pure *javascript* method where as `append` is a *jQuery* method.

Answer (score 0):

### I thought there is some confusion here so I'm going to clarify it.

Both 'append' and 'appendChild' are now native Javascript functions and can be used concurrently.

For example:

```js
let parent_div = document.querySelector('.hobbies');
let list_item = document.createElement('li');
list_item.style.color = 'red';
list_item.innerText = "Javascript added me here"

//running either one of these functions yield same result
const append_element = parent_div.append(list_item);
const append_child_element = parent_div.appendChild(list_item);
```

[image]

#### However, the key difference is the return value

e.g

```js
console.log(append_element) //returns undefined
```

whereas,

```js
console.log(append_child_element) // returns 'li' node
```

Hence, the return value of append_child method can be used to store it in a variable and use it later, whereas, append is use and throw (anonymous) function by nature.

[image]