# How to appendChild() on Jquery selected DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append child via jQuery to the on of selected HTML element.

My code:

```
var table = $(this).parent();
console.log(table)
table.appendChild(table_row);
```

Console:

```
[table.table.unit-list, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: tr] //log
... appendChild is not a function //error
```

Comment: because it's a jquery object use `append()` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> **Description:** Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
table.append(table_row);
```

Read about [Difference between append and appendChild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15926407/5336818)

Comment: That's the right answer! I will select it as a answer as soon as I can. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use pure JavaScript function **appendChild** with jQuery object.

To append your table use jQuery [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) `table.append(table_row);`

OR you can access to pure JavaScript object by getting very first element from jQuery `table[0]`. So it will be like `table[0].appendChild(table_row);`

Answer (score 0):

Since jquery $ function returns "Array" (actually it returns iterate-able  object)

you can use

`table[0].appendChild(tableRow)`

if you want to use appendChild .