# JavaScript append and prepend vs jQuery append and prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

> <sup>*QA Style*</sup>

I recently read an article and it says that JavaScript has implemented **`append`** and **`prepend`** methods inspired from jQuery.

It was a new knowledge for me because as far as I know to append an element, I had to use `element.appendChild` and to prepend an element, I had to use `element.insertBefore(newElement,element.children[0])`.

But jQuery's append and prepend have lots of features like accepting multiple arguments.

So my question is

**What are all the differences between JavaScript's append prepend and jQuery's append prepend have (in ease of use and in performance)**

> Not a dupe of [Append Vs AppendChild JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926325/append-vs-appendchild-jquery)

Comment: QA style. answered already. I believe that this method can reduce a lot of work in JavaScript if targeting a particular range of browsers. that is Chrome , FF and Opera

Answer (score 11):

## Tl; Dr

as usuall , JavaScript is faster than jQuery.

jQuery's append and prepend can be executed on a jQuery object which consist of multiple HTML elements but JavaScript's append and prepend can be executed only single HTML element.

jQuery's append and prepend can take HTML element, htmlString, jQuery object, plain text or array of HTML elements as input but JavaScript's append and prepend can take only HTML element and string(which will be converted to textNode).

## The long answer

JavaScript implemented append and prepend but the browser support is not upto the expectation.

According to MDN,

> The browser support is Chrome 54+, Firefox 49+ and Opera 39+.
>
> Tested on Edge and it is not working.

## 1. append

JavaScript

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

> The ParentNode.append method inserts a set of Node objects or DOMString objects after the last child of the ParentNode. DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

syntax

```
ParentNode.append(val1,val2,val3);
```

The `val` can be either an HTML element or a string(which will be converted to textNode)

jQuery

From [api.jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

syntax

```
jQueryCollection.append(val1,valn);
```

The `val` can be html string or element or text or  array or another jQuery object

## The difference between jQuery and JavaScript

jQuery append can be applied to a jQuery object that is a collection of HTML elements but JavaScript append can be applied to a single element

### Performance measurement

> The test is done to append things to 500 divs.

### JavaScript - append with HTML element

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(x=> x.append(document.createElement('span')));
```

> 6.0ms

### jQuery

```
$('div').append(document.createElement('span'));
```

> 70.0ms

### JavaScript append with plain text

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(x=> x.append('Hello'));
```

> 4.0ms

### jQuery append with plain text

```
$('div').append('Hello');
```

> 14.0ms
>
> as normal, JavaScript is faster than jQuery but jQuery can take more types of arguments and easy to write.

## 2. prepend

JavaScript

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

> The ParentNode.prepend method inserts a set of Node objects or DOMString objects before the first child of the ParentNode. DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

syntax

```
ParentNode.prepend(val1,val2,val3);
```

The `val` can be either an HTML element or a string(which will be converted to textNode) or array

jQuery

From [api.jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

syntax

```
jQueryCollection.prepend(val1,valn);
```

The `val` can be html string or element or text or  array or another jQuery object

## The difference between jQuery and JavaScript

jQuery prepend can be applied to a jQuery object that is a collection of HTML elements but JavaScript prepend can be applied to a single element

### Performance measurement

The test is done to prepend things to 500 divs.

### JavaScript - prepend with HTML element

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(x=> x.prepend(document.createElement('span')));
```

> 6.0ms

### jQuery

```
$('div').prepend(document.createElement('span'));
```

> 63.0ms

### JavaScript prepend with plain text

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(x=> x.prepend('Hello'));
```

> 4.005ms

### jQuery prepend with plain text

```
$('div').prepend('Hello');
```

> 17.0ms

same here. JavaScript is faster than jQuery but jQuery can take more types of arguments and easy to write.

---

#### A snippet with some codes used for the tests.

```js
function jsAppend(){
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(x=> {x.append(document.createElement('span'))});
}

function jsPrepend(){
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(x=> {x.prepend(document.createElement('span'))});
}

function jqAppend(){
  $('div').append($('<span></span'));
}

function jqPrepend(){
  $('div').prepend($('<span></span'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</body>
```