# differences between prepend and appendchild

Tags: javascript

I inserted a new row to my list and this is my code

```
 function newToDo() {
 var newTODoList = document.getElementById('toDoListInput');
 var newLine = document.createElement('li');
 var list = document.getElementById('list');
 newLine.textContent = newTODoList.value;
 newLine.class = 'newLineClass';
 list.prepend(newLine);
```

when I used appendchild instead of prepend my code didn't work correctly... what is diffrences between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript append and prepend vs jQuery append and prepend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408796/javascript-append-and-prepend-vs-jquery-append-and-prepend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prepend add item frond of list. append add item end of list. In snipped there is an example

```js
$('div')
    .append('<span>Append</span>')
    .prepend('<span>Prepend</span>')
    .before('<span>Before</span>')
    .after('<span>After</span>');
```

```css
div {
  border:2px solid #bbb;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px auto;
}

span {
  display:block;
  width:65px;
  font:bold 12px Arial,Sans-Serif;
  color:white;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:gray;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>-------content---------</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot... this example makes it easy to understand

Comment: The question is about vanilla JS, not in jQuery context. The answer should speak about the differences between [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) and [prepend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend)

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer, if anyone knows the genuine answer, your assistance would be appreciated!