# Create a url link on a text inside a cell using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, database

I want to create a table with headers.
To create the rows and columns in the tbody, I will query the db and populate the cells using javascript.
More importantly, I want to link the first cell of each row only using a string variable.
The below codes work well, but there is a problem - only one row is linked instead of all the rows. please see image below.

The table should look like this...

```
sn   |   station name  |     address       |  zone
------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  lions building | 2, moloney str,   |  2
     |  police station | lagos island,     |   
------------------------------------------------------------
2    | marako police   | new market road,  |  2
     | station         | oniru, vi, lagos. |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the above table, sn (1) and sn (2) should be linked, but it is not. Please see code and screenshot below.

variables declaration here

```
var stationName;
var zone;
var address;
var city;
var lga;
var state;
var status;
var period;
var stationid;
var db = openDatabase('pcrdb', '3.6.19', 'Police Criminal Records Database', 500*1024*1024);//500MB
```

this function queries the records from the database and parse them to variables

```
function viewStations(){
document.getElementById("viewbutton").disabled = true;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM STATIONS', [], function (tx, results) {
for(i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){ 
rows = results.rows.item(i);
//stationid = ("<a href = '"javascript:void(0)"'; onclick = editStation(" + rows.st_id + ");> +rows.st_id+ </a>");
stationid = rows.st_id;                 
stationName = rows.station;
address     = rows.address+", "+rows.city+", "+rows.lga;
zone        = rows.zone;

createCells();
}

}, null); 
}); 
}
```

create the table rows and columns here

```
function createCells() {
var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
var row = document.createElement("tr");

var td1 = document.createElement("td");
td1.setAttribute("align","center");
td1.setAttribute("id","sn");

var td2 = document.createElement("td");
td2.setAttribute("align","center");
td2.setAttribute("id","stn");

var td3 = document.createElement("td");
td3.setAttribute("align","center");
td3.setAttribute("id","ad");

var td4 = document.createElement("td");
td4.setAttribute("align","center");
td4.setAttribute("id","zn");

var cellText1 = document.createTextNode(stationid);//append text to each cell
var celltext2 = document.createTextNode(stationName);
var celltext3 = document.createTextNode(address);
var cellText4 = document.createTextNode(zone);

td1.appendChild(cellText1);
td2.appendChild(celltext2);
td3.appendChild(celltext3);
td4.appendChild(cellText4);

row.appendChild(td1);//append columns to rows
row.appendChild(td2);
row.appendChild(td3);
row.appendChild(td4);
tbody.appendChild(row);//append row to tbody
```

this is the linked stationid. Here, only the cell of the first row is linked. The second row is not linked.

```
var linktd = document.getElementById("sn").innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='editStation(" + stationid + ");'>"+stationid+"</a>";
}
```

this function would be called when the linked id is clicked.

```
function editStation(){
alert("This link is not working yet. The table id is: "+stationid);
}
```

this is the html code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm col-md col-lg col-xl">
<table id="stationtable" class="table table-borderless table-hover" style="border-style:solid; border-width:0px;width:100%; height:auto; margin-radius:5px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="color:brown; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; width:5%; text-align:center;">SN</th>
<th style="color:brown; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;width:35% text-align:center;">STATION NAME</th>
<th style="color:brown; font-weight:bold; font-size:18; width:40% text-align:center;">ADDRESS</th>
<th style="color:brown; font-weight:bold; font-size:18; width:20% text-align:center;">ZONE</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody">
<!--<tr id="tr">

</tr>-->
</tbody>
</table>

<button id="viewbutton" onclick="viewStations()">CLICK TO DISPLAY STATIONS </button>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Using all caps is generally considered shouting online.  Using all caps in your title is not advised.

Comment: Please, format your code properly.

Comment: I have formatted the code again... thanks.

Comment: At what point do you populate those cells? (sn, stn, ad, zn)

Comment: For array indexing in javascript you need to use **square brackets**: `results.rows.item[i]`

Comment: You are appending content to existing TDs, i suggest you change your function to append a new set of TDs to your tbody

Comment: @Peter B, square brackets work well with arrays...but brackets alone work well with data binding to variables.

Comment: @JPdelaTorre, using the For...loop, the cells get populated with data from results.rows.item(i)

Comment: @EulerRibeiroSudbrack, do I have to create the TDs from the for...loop statement?

Comment: @EulerRibeiroSudbrack, I have changed the createElement function to append a new set of TDs. This way, the data are displayed on the same row.... it does not create a new row for the next data

Comment: @Eyo i have posted a answer with a new createCells :)

Comment: Okay!!! Thanks guys, I have worked around it and it is displaying very well. I want to commend @EulerRibeiroSudbrack, who suggested that I change my codes. However, I did more than he suggested. I created a new <tr> inside a <tbody> and bound the,<tr> to the <tbody>. Thanks guys... I will repost the entire code.

Comment: Please guys, kindly check the codes in the question blocks. I have added a new code depicting a problem that I cannot solve. I need to create a link on a row using the createTextNode() method. It's workings without properly formatting the link reference. I need your help, please.

Comment: @Eyo I updated my answer. You really need to avoid using so many ids.

Comment: @JPdelaTorre, please see my comments below your edited codes down. I have also added screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are meant to be unique. That's why the first time you do `td1.setAttribute("id","sn");` that becomes the one and only cell with that ID.

What you need to do is use references and not IDs, like this:

```
var idCell = document.createElement('td');
idCell.innerHtml = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editStation(' + stationId + ')">' + stationId + '</a>';
tr.appendChild(idCell)
```

The code below works as you'd expect and it is more memory efficient. I changed your HTML a little bit (moved repetitive styles one level up and removed that table row that you don't actually need):

```
<body onload="viewStations()">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm col-md col-lg col-xl">
        <table id="stationtable" class="table table-borderless table-hover" style="border-style:solid; border-width:0px;width:100%; height:auto; margin-radius:5px;">
            <thead>
                <tr style="color:brown; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; text-align:center;">
                    <th style="width:5%">SN</th>
                    <th style="width:35%">STATION NAME</th>
                    <th style="width:40%">ADDRESS</th>
                    <th style="width:20%">ZONE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button id="view" onclick="viewStations()">LOAD STATIONS </button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And here's the Javascript (I changed your functions a little):

```
// This is the only variable you need.
var db = openDatabase('pcrdb', '3.6.19', 'Police Criminal Records Database', 500*1024*1024);//500MB

function editStation(stationId){
    alert("This link is not working yet. The station id is: " + stationId);
}

function viewStations (){
    document.getElementById("viewbutton").disabled = true;

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM STATIONS', [], function (tx, results) {

        // There's no need to save the information in global
        // variables, just pass on the object you need.
        for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
             createCells(results.rows.item(i));
         };
        }, null); 
    }); 
}

function createCells(row) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");

    // You need to create new lines
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var stationId = row['stationid'];

    // In this case your first cell needs a different treatment 
    var idCell = document.createElement('td');
    idCell.innerHtml = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editStation(' + stationId + ')">' + stationId + '</a>';
    tr.appendChild(idCell);

    // When handling several near identical lines it is better
    // to just use arrays. In this one, your columns are simply
    // properties of an object.
    ['stationName', 'address', 'zone'].forEach(
        function (column) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerText = row[column];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    )

    // finally append the new line
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: I also appreciate your code. It is nice though, but I had gone with @Euler's suggestions. I adapted his code and it worked well for me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried your code, and I noticed that, it did not actually perform exactly what you intended. For instance, idCell.innerHtml = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editStation(' + stationId + ')">' + stationId + '</a>'; tr.appendChild(idCell); did not work at all. However, I edited your function also. the column names in the Station table are: [st_id, station, address, zone]. So, I edited stationId to st_id. It actually displayed the records, but the records did not follow the same row definition as indicated in the table headers.

Comment: I have uploaded screenshots of your own codes to Google Drive... here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jQiPAitMBax0q6VVzElPswazkBszyRAK

Comment: from the code that produced the above screenshots, I commented out these lines: /*var idCell = document.createElement('td');
 idCell.innerHtml = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editStation(' + stationId + ')">' + stationId + '</a>';
 tr.appendChild(idCell);*/ and the records were rendered properly, but still no linked column. See the screenshots for the corrected version here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jdhE-sonU9GkMWDIHfYs7jFA6h482csu

Comment: @Eyo You can't just remove the code that adds a link and expect it to work.

Comment: @Eyo I'll edit my response to explain what is wrong with your code.

Comment: that code which you intended to add a link, neither added any link nor rendered the cells properly. But when I commented it out, the rows however, rendered properly but I need to find a way to link the rows.

Comment: Here's a working example in Codepen. You just need to copy the code. https://codepen.io/jpidelatorre/pen/xjeNYp

Comment: I looked at your suggestion on Codepen. But, the sample displayed table did not have any cell linked as declared in idCell.innerHTML ='<a> ..... </a>'; statement.

Comment: Fixed. There was a typo (`innerHtml` instead of `innerHTML`).

Comment: Yeah! I saw it also. The correction was effected and it worked. I need to mark your answer as best... which of them is yours?

Comment: I think you just found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Function createCells adapted to create new set of rows:

```
function createCells() {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    var td3 = document.createElement("td");
    var td4 = document.createElement("td");

    td1.innerText = stationid;
    td2.innerText = stationName;
    td3.innerText = address;
    td4.innerText = zone;

    td1.setAttribute("align","center");
    td2.setAttribute("align","center");
    td3.setAttribute("align","center");
    td4.setAttribute("align","center");

    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);

    tbody.append(row)
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice your code above. However, I have adapted your code and changed tbody.append(row) to tbody.appendChild(row), and it is working. I will mark your answer correct.

Comment: @EulerRebeiro, what is the difference between append() and appendChild()?

Comment: @eyo googling "append vs appendchild" gives you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926325/append-vs-appendchild-jquery

Comment: append accept text and can receive multiple arguments, u can do row.append(td1,td2,td3,td4) instead :)
for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: I have updated the function to call append() only one time

Comment: @EulerRibeiroSudbrack, thank you very much. I will like to try that also. Thank you all the same. I appreciate.

Comment: @EulerRibeiroSudbrack, I tried your method, row.append(td1,td2,td3,td4). It did not work. So, I changed it back to row.appendChild(td1).....row.appendChild(td4).

Comment: @Eyo now i see, its not compatible with IE and Edge

Answer (score 2):

this is the javascript code

```
//variables declaration
    //alert("Variables Initialization");
    var stationName;
    var zone;
    var address;
    var city;
    var lga;
    var state;
    var status;
    var period;
    var stationid;
    var db = openDatabase('pcrdb', '3.6.19', 'Police Criminal Records Database', 500*1024*1024);//500MB

function viewStations(){
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM STATIONS', [], function (tx, results) {
            for(i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){ 
                stationid   = results.rows.item(i).st_id;
                stationName = results.rows.item(i).station;
                address     = results.rows.item(i).address;
                city        = results.rows.item(i).city;
                lga         = results.rows.item(i).lga;
                state       = results.rows.item(i).state;
                zone        = results.rows.item(i).zone;            
                createCells();
            }

        }, null); 
    }); 
}

function createCells() {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    /*var td1 = document.getElementById("sn");
    var td2 = document.getElementById("stn");
    var td3 = document.getElementById("ad");
    var td4 = document.getElementById("zn");*/

    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.setAttribute("align","center");
    td1.setAttribute("id","sn");

    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.setAttribute("align","center");
    td2.setAttribute("id","stn");

    var td3 = document.createElement("td");
    td3.setAttribute("align","center");
    td3.setAttribute("id","ad");

    var td4 = document.createElement("td");
    td4.setAttribute("align","center");
    td4.setAttribute("id","zn");

    var cellText1 = document.createTextNode(stationid);
    var celltext2 = document.createTextNode(stationName);
    var celltext3 = document.createTextNode(address);
    var cellText4 = document.createTextNode(zone);


    //alert("Station Name: "+stationName);

    td1.appendChild(cellText1);
    td2.appendChild(celltext2);
    td3.appendChild(celltext3);
    td4.appendChild(cellText4);

    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);

    tbody.appendChild(row);[this is the new image for the workable codes][1]

}
```

this is the html code

```
<body onload="viewStations()">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm col-md col-lg col-xl">
        <table id="stationtable" class="table table-borderless table-hover" style="border-style:solid; border-width:0px;width:100%; height:auto; margin-radius:5px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="color:brown; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; width:5%; text-align:center;">SN</th>
                    <th style="color:brown; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;width:35% text-align:center;">STATION NAME</th>
                    <th style="color:brown; font-weight:bold; font-size:18; width:40% text-align:center;">ADDRESS</th>
                    <th style="color:brown; font-weight:bold; font-size:18; width:20% text-align:center;">ZONE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
                <!--<tr id="tr">

                </tr>-->
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button id="view" onclick="viewStations()">LOAD STATIONS </button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```